# How to use the "PictureBox.Image.Flags" property

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio, properties

I'm programming in *Visual Basic.NET* in *Visual studio 2017 RC*.

In my form, I'm using a **picture box** that is named **"PictureBox"**. I was trying to get information about the picture displayed inside the **picture box** using the **PictureBox.Image.Flags** **property** so the user can view these information.

But it seems very difficult to work with this **property** as it returns a value that is a sum of other values.

What is the right and most efficient way of using this **property**? If it won't work, is there another way of representing the **image flags** information without using this **property**?

Comment: As MSDN and Object Browser explain it is the `bitwise combination of System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFlags for this System.Drawing.Image`  Its an Enum so you can use `flags.HasFlag(...)` to test for a value

Comment: @Plutonix Where to use  flags.HasFlag(...) and where?

Comment: Hasflag does not seem to be attached to flags @Plutonix

Comment: @Trevor I agree. Flags don't have a "HasFlag" method.

Comment: Then use the more traditional And method as in my answer. It does the same thing as HasFlags anyway.

Comment: You have to cast/convert it because for whatever reason the property is integer.  `Dim imgFlags As ImageFlags = CType(TheImg.Flags, ImageFlags)`  then you may not even need HasFlag some/all(?) of the flags are represented in the Type such as `imgFlags.HasAlpha`

Comment: refresh the page.. you should see the answer

Comment: @plutonix... sigh... isn't that the dumbest thing... Not you... the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to test individual flags use the **And** function

```
    If (PictureBox1.Image.Flags And System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFlags.ColorSpaceGray) <> 0 Then
```

or Multiples

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFlags


If (PictureBox1.Image.Flags And (ColorSpaceGray + ColorSpaceRgb)) <> 0 Then
```

**Alternative**

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFlags

If CType(PictureBox1.Image.Flags, ImageFlags).HasFlag(ColorSpaceGray) then
```

Or multiples

```
If CType(PictureBox1.Image.Flags, ImageFlags).HasFlag(CType(ColorSpaceGray  + ColorSpaceRgb, ImageFLags)) then
```

Comment: the value in brackets will be non zero if the flag is set. The And in this case is a binary And.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But I don't understand how "
 
the value in brackets will be non zero if the flag is set".

Comment: YOu have to understand how AND really works in binary... 1010 AND 0010 = 0010...  which is not zero.

Comment: Why does the code before  AND represent 1010 in binary and the code after it represent 0010 in binary? I would be grateful if you could suggest an article or something explaining this. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Every number in a computer is a binary number... 1 is 01, 2 is 10 etc. Each FLAG is a binary position... i.e. 1 is bit 1 2 is bit 2, 4 is bit 3 etc. Doing a binary AND function does a bitwise and on every bit. SO You are anding the actual value with a Mask... that filters the bits you care about.

Comment: The 1010 was just an example.